# Unable to consistently set size of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UItableViewController, with a UITextField in each cell, pretty basic. I decided to get a bit fancy and alternate the row colors by setting the background color of the text field.

What I noticed is that the text field background color does not match up with the table rows. The width is shorter and the height and position is wrong too.

I tried setting the dimensions of the frame of the text field in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I also tried the same in willDisplayCell. I also tried to muck around with other frames, like the cell frame, to no avail.

I've had some some luck in setting the text field frame size in layoutSubviews in my UITableViewCell subclass, but it still acts strangely. When the table first displays, everything looks right. I click my edit button, and everything still looks right. I click the done button and I'm back to the old problem with both the width and height too short. Checking in the debugger, I am setting everything to the correct values.

More Information:
I have the same problem with some tables which have UILabels instead of UITextFields. All of the tables have fixed size rows. I initially set up the tables with the interface builder, but I'm trying to set the frame sizes programmatically. I am using the latest and greatest Xcode 5 (5.1.1).

Anyone have any suggestions? Where am I supposed to set the frame size? Is there another object that I should be setting the size of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting the background color of the textField to clearColor, and then set the background color of the cell.contentView.

Comment: That seems to have worked. thanks. Does this mean that my text fields are not properly aligned with the cell?

Comment: looks like there is some problem with the way that the text field and labels are aligned. I've set their height and width to match the height and width of the contentView, and the origin to be (0,0). The label appears in the upper right of the cell with the buttons of the serif characters cut off. As soon as I select a row, the label text becomes centered vertically and the bottoms are no longer cut off. As I select rows, other rows shift between the two states.

Comment: So which of the following tools are you using: storyboard/autolayout, programmatic/autolayout, storyboard/struts-and-springs, programmatic/autoresizingmask, or none of the above?  Note that the last one isn't really an option, you're using one of the first four whether you know it or not.

Comment: I laid out the screen initially with the storyboard and tweaked things programatically.